# Passing parameters to the aggregating function in Reshape (R language)

Tags: r, reshape

I am using Reshape in R to apply a function to different variables of my dataset.

mydata.m is the output from melt. Amongst its columns are "Diagnosis", a factor denoting an eating disorder, and schoolIDEN, which indicates which schools the subjects attend. I want to use cast to apply a function to each Diagnosis. schoolIDEN needs to be passed to the function. The value column contains a binary indicator for each diagnosis. (Background: several thousand teens were assessed for a bunch of eating disorders and the diagnosis coded for each diagnosis and each teen.)

```
cast(mydata.m, Diagnosis ~ ., myFun, group = schoolIDEN) -> temp
```

myFun is the following:

```
myFun <- function(x, group){
    out.gl <- glmer(x ~ (1|group), family=binomial(link="logit"))
    output <- inv.logit(confint.merMod(out.gl, method="Wald"))
    output
}
```

Basically, for each Diagnosis, I want to calculate a confidence interval for the mean, adjusting for schoolIDEN (a random effect).

However, I get an error. myFun can't find "group" when it gets called.

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
```

argument "group" is missing, with no default

Somehow, my random effect is not getting passed to the aggregating function.

I could have done this without reshape, looping through my data frame, but I thought this would be quicker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the aggregation function is done for each column separately. And that the additional parameters that you pass via `...` are not evaluated in the same environment as the `data.frame` nor are they subset into corresponding groups. Thus `cast` would't really be a good choice for you here.

I work with mostly base functions so I might try this by splitting up the `data.frame` and then running an `sapply` to do the regression. Something like

```
myFun2 <- function(dd){
    out.gl <- glmer(?response? ~ (1|group), dd family=binomial(link="logit"))
    output <- inv.logit(confint.merMod(out.gl, method="Wald"))
    output
}

dx <- split(my.data, my.data$Diagnosis)
sapply(dx, myFun2)
```

So now myFun2 will be passed a `data.frame` subset for each diagnosis. I wasn't sure what your response variable name in the data set was so you'll want to set that.